# How to change ZIndex inside a bound ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I simply created 3 borders in a StackPanel like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Border Width="100" Height="30" Background="Red" BorderBrush="DarkRed" BorderThickness="4" Margin="0" >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
        <Border Width="100" Height="30" Background="Blue" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="4" Margin="-10,0,0,0" >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
        <Border Width="100" Height="30" Background="Green" BorderBrush="DarkGreen" BorderThickness="4" Margin="-10,0,0,0" >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
```

the xaml will layout 3 different colors borders:

[image]

When i mouse over the blue one, it'll on the top of others:

[image]

But when I move all of these into a ItemsControl, mouse on blue border no longer on the top of others, it just stay it's original ZIndex.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="BorderTemplate">
        <Border Width="100" Height="30" >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkRed"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-10,0,0,0"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="3">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-10,0,0,0"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Borders}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BorderTemplate}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

[image]

[image]

So why Panel.ZIndex worked in StackPanel but not work in ItemsControl->StackPanel?

Comment: ZIndex is meant to be used in Canvas. So much code and not so much effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZIndex is by no means limited to canvas, so let's not push that idea off on other readers Maximus. However, since you're now loading your stuff as an `ItemTemplate`, using just a `ContentPresenter`, so you're basically sandboxing your object in a panel not associated to the overall DOM. Try instead to throw your influence at the `ContentPresenter` as the object being your container instead of disassociated children nested in it individually. Something like this (after you pull the same triggers off each Border of course).

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.